# Split Varchar into Character in MySQL

Tags: mysql, split, character

I have a varchar field with length 6. I want to split into single characters in MySQL. Currently I have tried with following script:

```
col = '123456';
{
select SUBSTRING(col,1, 1),
SUBSTRING(col, 2,1),
SUBSTRING(col, 3,1),
SUBSTRING(col, 4,1),
SUBSTRING(col, 5,1),
SUBSTRING(col, 6,1)
from tbl_table
}
```

The above script works but is there any other solution for this.

Thank You.

Comment: What other solution you are looking for? Do you mean avoiding multiple substring in select statement?

Answer (score 2):

There is no string split function in MySQL. so you have to create your own function. Use below link.This will help you

**Split delimited strings**

The following example function takes 3 parameters, performs an operation using an SQL function, and returns the result.

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

**Usage**

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
```

**Example**

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('a|bb|ccc|dd', '|', 3) as third;

+-------+
| third |
+-------+
| ccc   |
+-------+
```

Credits:http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: That's a pretty handy function... for somebody else's issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be use whatever (unknown) scripting language you are using to do the split.  Otherwise, if it works, don't fix it.

To add some actual value to this answer, I will add that it would be a good practice to meaningfully name the columns:

```
col = '123456';
{
select SUBSTRING(col,1, 1) AS value1,
SUBSTRING(col, 2,1) AS value2,
SUBSTRING(col, 3,1) AS value3,
SUBSTRING(col, 4,1) AS value4,
SUBSTRING(col, 5,1) AS value5,
SUBSTRING(col, 6,1) AS value6
from tbl_table
}
```

Also, if you find yourself doing this, it means you are not properly using a RDBMS and each of those should be in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that run on the string in a while loop until there isn't any results (I've added $id for JOIN clause):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_split_str_to_chars`($id INT, $str VARCHAR(800), $empty_table BIT) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

    DECLARE counter int;
    DECLARE length int;
    SET counter = 1;
    SET length = length($str);
    
    IF $empty_table THEN
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_chars;    
    END IF;
                    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_chars AS (SELECT $id as id, SUBSTR($str, counter, 1) as val where 1 = 2);
        
    WHILE counter <= length DO        
        INSERT INTO tmp_chars
        SELECT $id, SUBSTR($str, counter, 1);
        
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
        
    RETURN length;
END
```

then you can call it like that:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_chars;
SELECT  SUM(fn_split_str_to_chars(ID, FieldToSplit, 0))
FROM    MyTable as b;
SELECT * FROM tmp_chars;
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT  fn_split_str_to_chars(null, '123456', 1);
SELECT * FROM tmp_chars;
```

We don't need to empty the temporary table, the function will take care of that.